# Python ETREE parsing of a windows XML output

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have trouble understanding how I'm supposed to access the XML format outputed by powershell. I'm doing this in Python, with etree.

The XML is a succession of these, that I can get to by itering over root:

```
  <Obj RefId="3">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <ToString>CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=xx</ToString>
    <Props>
      <S N="DistinguishedName">CN=Guest,CN=Users,DC=xxx,DC=xx</S>
      <B N="Enabled">false</B>
      <Nil N="GivenName" />
      <Obj N="MemberOf" RefId="4">
        <TNRef RefId="1" />
        <LST>
          <S>CN=Guests,CN=Builtin,DC=xxx,DC=xx</S>
        </LST>
      </Obj>
      <S N="Name">Guest</S>
      <S N="ObjectClass">user</S>
      <G N="ObjectGUID">xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx</G>
      <S N="SamAccountName">Guest</S>
      <Obj N="SID" RefId="5">
        <TNRef RefId="2" />
        <ToString>S-1-5-21-1111111-11111-111111111-111</ToString>
        <Props>
          <I32 N="BinaryLength">28</I32>
          <S N="AccountDomainSid">S-2-2-2-22222-222-22222</S>
          <S N="Value">S-2-2-22-2222222-222222-22222-2222</S>
        </Props>
      </Obj>
      <Nil N="Surname" />
      <Nil N="UserPrincipalName" />
    </Props>
  </Obj>
```

I'm able to get to the "props" element by doing:

```
  tree = etree.parse(file)
  root = tree.getroot()
  props = root.find('Props')
```

Now let's say I want to get the "SamAccountName", I don't understand how to reach it. If I print the keys of the element, I get non unique keys:

```
['N']
['N']
['N']
['RefId', 'N']
['N']
['N']
['N']
['N']
['RefId', 'N']
['N']
['N']
```

The items method gives me tupple, which look like the unique identifier I'm after:

```
[('N', 'DistinguishedName')]
[('N', 'Enabled')]
[('N', 'GivenName')]
[('RefId', '4'), ('N', 'MemberOf')]
[('N', 'Name')]
[('N', 'ObjectClass')]
[('N', 'ObjectGUID')]
[('N', 'SamAccountName')]
[('RefId', '5'), ('N', 'SID')]
[('N', 'Surname')]
[('N', 'UserPrincipalName')]
```

I tried a bunch of different things along the lines of:

```
props.find('{N}SamAccountName')
props.find('S N="SamAccountName"')
```

But if finds nothing. The only way I can get to the actual value is:

```
chicken = props[7]
print(chicken.text)
```

I'm sure there is a more robust way to get to this, but I can't find the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an XPath expression

In your case this one should work

```
test = props.find('S/[@N="SamAccountName"]')
```

You can find out more about them here:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp

and

https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support

Comment: Awesome! I'll work my way with this through the other ones I need.